# Compilation error, can not find Controls used by WSProc

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I've got a small project in Lazarus, and all was fine until i wanted to add Library to my program. Since then I'm getting this error:

```
wsproc.pp(27,24) Fatal: Can not find Controls used by WSProc,
ppu=/usr/local/lib/fpc/2.6.4/units/i386-darwin/univint/Controls.ppu, package LCLBase
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controls unit doesn't belong to fpc and can not be found in `.../fpc/2.6.4/units/...`.

Instead it's part of lazarus. Search for the "lcl" directory and add it to your ppu path.

Comment: I'm a bit new to lazarus, could you instruct me a bit :)?

Comment: Now i get `/Developer/lazarus/lcl/widgetset/wsreferences.pp(20,2) Fatal: Can't open include file "lcl_defines.inc"
` message

Comment: @TomaszKasperek - I don't know how to give instructions to a bit for you ;-) Ok, seriously. I've never programmed for a Mac and I don't know how mature this branch of lazarus is. Looking at my win version, it seems that a lot of the paths are implicit. Is the lazarus path under "tools/settings" ok? As a workaround you could also add the `.../lcl/include` path to the include files field. (project settings) For me sometimes it helped to do uninstall, delete all eventually leftover files and reinstall.